# hide() with Jquery works not 100%

Tags: jquery, hide, slideshow

I have the following page:
http://www.ontdekjewintersport.nl/

The page is setup with 3 slides which are being controlled by the buttons at the bottom of the page. On the first slide, the 'vorige' (previous) button on the left is hidden and the 'volgende' (next) button is shown on the right. On the next slide both buttons are shown and on slide 3 we try to hide the next button. But this button doesn't hide.

I tried all kind of options, like completely emptying the tag with the ID, remove the class and of the span but none of them worked. I'm not struggling and hope you can help me out, how I can hide this next button on the last slide.

Any more information needed, please let me know.

With kind regards

Ralf

Comment: .hide() DOES work 100%. So the problem is with your implementation. And without seeing some code, we can't help.

Comment: What maxedison means is: On StackOverflow it's preferred to put your (simplified) code inside your question or, if it's too complicated, on http://jsfiddle.net so that others can easily look at it and highlight the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your code and each slide has its own set of next/previous buttons. The issue is that each of these buttons has the same ID (`leftControl`/`rightControl`). Every element on your page that has an ID should have a unique ID. That I believe is the reason your code is not hiding the last "next" button; your code finds the first element with the ID of `rightControl` and it hides it (which I verified in Firebug).

If you change your selectors to use the classes of the next/previous buttons (`volgende`/`vorige`) they will all be affected when you run the code rather than just finding the first button.

```
function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide();}
    else{ $('#leftControl').show(); }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide(); /*$('#extra').hide(); */}
    else{ $('#rightControl').show(); }
}
```

Could change to:

```
function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('.vorige').hide();}
    else{ $('.vorige').show(); }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('.volgende').hide(); /*$('#extra').hide(); */}
    else{ $('.volgende').show(); }
}
```

Or more specifically if you want to only hide the first "previous" or the last "next" button:

```
function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('.vorige:first').hide();}
    else{ $('.vorige').show(); }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('.volgende:last').hide(); /*$('#extra').hide(); */}
    else{ $('.volgende').show(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper, this worked perfectly! Sometime the solution is right in front of your/mine nose.

Comment: Welcome to the community, if you post another question it is helpful to post relavant code directy into your question. If you feel that your code is too complex (with lots of JS, CSS & HTML) then it's common to use http://jsfiddle.net. If you follow this practice you will get more attention for your questions. Again, welcome!